# The meaning of "Обеспечение"?

Tags: перевод, грамматика

This another sentence from a train "перечень".

"Обеспечение чаем или кофе с сахаром в любое время суток по просьбе пассажиров."

In my slovar the word: "Обеспечение" is not translated very good. They link it to commodities and social welfare, "security", "well being" and "reliability" which in my opinion do not really fit this context.

Could the word "Обеспечение" perhaps be translated into: "Provision", to provide tea and coffee...on request.

The reference to: "at any time of the day" in the sentence does that mean there is a 24hr service on the train or is it only during the daytime or up to bedtime?

Comment: Next time you see _-ение_, look for _-ивать_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First a side note: these kinds of documents are written in Russian officialese, which had been influenced by German and French. Normally, such nominalizations are not used in spoken language.

Thus said:

> Could the word "Обеспечение" perhaps be translated into: "Provision", to provide tea and coffee...on request.

Yes, it could, but that's not how you should translate it. This phrase just means "passengers are provided tea or coffee and sugar any time of the day".

> The reference to: "at any time of the day" in the sentence does that mean there is a 24hr service on the train or is it only during the daytime or up to bedtime?

Yes, it does. There's always a conductor on duty who, sometimes a little bit reluctantly, would make you a glass of tea and bring it to your compartment.

Comment: Highly appreciate taking time to elaborate a little on the background. Something that is never (in my end) covered otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of *обеспечение* as *provision* is right in this situation. Here it's sinonymous with *снабжение*.

And yes, there is a 24hr service on the train.

Comment: Highly appreciate the response.